# Remove unused import and variable on save action in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How can I remove unused import and variable on **save action** in eclipse.
I have option Ctrl+Shift+O. but it remove only unused import.
I want to remove unused variable also.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Eclipse can remove only unused imports using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. For unused varibales/functions there is no such shortcut(AFAIK). Eclipse by default will show warning message for such type of variables, if it doesn't then you can enable it from `windows > preferences > java > compiler > error/warnings > Unnecessary code`

## UPDATE:

There is one way to remove unused variables:

Go to `windows > preferences > Java > code style > cleanup`

[image]

Edit the built in profile.

In the unnecessary code tab check `remove unused private members` and press ok.

[image]

Select the active profile as the one you have just created.

Now to apply profile, open the context menu in the Java Editor and select `Source > Clean Up`[image].

Answer (score 25):

Here is how you can do it:

In Eclipse Go to Window -> Preferences-> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions and click on Perform the selected actions on save: Organize imports.

Enjoy!

Comment: Is there any way to make it just remove the unused imports without "organizing" them? This feature sometimes causes conflicts because we don't force an IDE on our devs